# ggplot font family change between versions

Tags: windows, r, fonts, ggplot2

In the following picture you can see the same part of a ggplot graph, created in two different (windows) machines. Above each graph I have written the versions of the related packages. I am not using any `font family` setting in the ggplot call. Why do I get different fonts with the most recent version? (The change reminds me of the effect that `Cleartype` setting has in smoothing font edges)

[image: picture]

Comment: What windows versions do the two machines run? And, do you use the extrafont package, or have GTK & Cairo installed?

Comment: Actually it looks like the same font in both plots, but one with and one without antialiasing. So it has to do with the setup of your machine and of your R installation.

Comment: Both machines run Win XP Professional - Version 2002 - service pack 3. I have tried extrafont but it has no effect because it's not a case of a different font. As you said the font is the same - I think it's Arial. I have GTK in both machines. No cairo.

Comment: This must be down to different antialiasing settings. Please check Control Panel > Display Settings > Appearance > Effects > "Smooth edges of screen fonts" setting, and also from IE's menu Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab > "Always use ClearType for HTML". One or both of these settings may be different between the two machines.

Comment: Could be a -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased setting.

Comment: @Theodore Lytras Both machines have the same settings (enabled).

Comment: If the versions of everything are the same, why do the window borders look different?

Comment: @hadley When I took the screenshot, the second machine was set to Windows classic visual style. I changed it to XP style but had nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to take a look at this page, http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Fonts/, for some tips on dealing with font issues with ggplot/ggplot2. Also there is an example `R` script that will generate a table of all the fonts rendered so you can compare them a little easier between the 2 systems.

#### make_font_table.R

```
fonttable <- read.table(header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                        text='
Short,Canonical,
mono,Courier,
sans,Helvetica,
serif,Times
,AvantGarde
,Bookman
,Helvetica-Narrow
,NewCenturySchoolbook
,Palatino
,URWGothic
,URWBookman
,NimbusMon
URWHelvetica,NimbusSan
,NimbusSanCond
,CenturySch
,URWPalladio
URWTimes,NimbusRom
')

fonttable$pos <- 1:nrow(fonttable)

library(reshape2)
fonttable <- melt(fonttable, id.vars="pos", measure.vars=c("Short","Canonical"),
                  variable.name="NameType", value.name="Font")

# Make a table of faces. Make sure factors are ordered correctly
facetable <- data.frame(Face = factor(c("plain","bold","italic","bold.italic"),
                                      levels = c("plain","bold","italic","bold.italic")))

fullfonts <- merge(fonttable, facetable)

library(ggplot2)
pf <- ggplot(fullfonts, aes(x=NameType, y=pos)) + 
             geom_text(aes(label=Font, family=Font, fontface=Face)) +
             facet_wrap(~ Face, ncol=2)

pf
```

You can run it like so:

```
% R
> source ("make_font_table.R")
> pf
```

[image: ss of font table]

**NOTICE**: Only some of the fonts (Timea, Helvetica, Courier) are actually getting rendered.

Also you might want to check out the [extrafont-package](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/blob/master/README.md). Finally this [post](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html) shows how to use the extrafont-package so that you get better looking fonts rendered in your output.